# How can I expand the list view in Flutter to fit the remaining screen space below it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app where I want to display a list of items in a ListView. I want the ListView to expand and fill the remaining space on the screen below it. Additionally, I want the layout to adapt to different screen sizes. I've tried flexible widgets but it always leads to some kind of error so I stayed away.

Reference Image:

[image]

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// [code removed for brevity]
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    // [code removed for brevity]
    body: editAndViewMode(context),
  );
}

Widget editAndViewMode(BuildContext context) {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

 // [code removed for brevity]

 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hcgradeapp/providers/gpa_calculator_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../constants/const.dart';
import '../constants/icons.dart';
import '../themes/theme_const.dart';

class GPACalculator extends StatefulWidget {
  const GPACalculator({super.key});

  @override
  State<GPACalculator> createState() => _GPACalculatorState();
}
 // [code removed for brevity]

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("GPA Calculator"),
        leading: drawerIcon(),
        centerTitle: true,
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: context.watch<GpaProvider>().editMode
                ? const Icon(CustomIcons.eye)
                : const Icon(Icons.edit_rounded),
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<GpaProvider>().toggleMode();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: sideDrawer(context),
      drawerEdgeDragWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      body: editAndViewMode(context),
    );
  }
}

Widget editAndViewMode(BuildContext context) {
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  // This is what you're looking for!
  void scrollDown() {
    scrollController.animateTo(
      scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }

  if (context.watch<GpaProvider>().editMode) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // Existing code removed for brevity

        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.52,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: context.watch<GpaProvider>().courseValues.length,
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            controller: scrollController,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              // Code for individual list items
            },
          ),
        ),

        // Existing code removed for brevity
      ],
    );
  } else {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // Existing code removed for brevity

        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.52,
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: context.watch<GpaProvider>().courseValues.length,
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              // Code for individual list items
            },
          ),
        ),

        // Existing code removed for brevity
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SizedBox has it own height:
`height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.52,`

So just add Expanded and ListView is child of it. Expanded will take remaining space

```
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.52,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: context.watch<GpaProvider>().courseValues.length,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              controller: scrollController,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                // Code for individual list items
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return StoryListTile(items[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
```